# data proccessing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have set up a number of columns with some data-numbers.

I would like also to present some data resulting from processing these columns: For each of these columns i would like to know the product of each cell with a column constant: `C1 *k`, `C2 *k`, ... where `C` is one of these columns and `k` the constant being assigned to the specific column `C`. I could do that by adding side by side columns, but then the sheet would be very long in x-direction.

Initially, I thought about using hyperlinks which would direct to a second sheet: just clicking to `C1` of 'sheet 1' would direct to – let's say `C1` of 'sheet 2' (`=Sheet1!C1*k`) and do that for all the cells of sheet 1.

Are there any suggestions for a more clever way to do that? For example would it be possible to alternate the contents of a column with some way, e.g. between `C1` and `C1 *k`? I also thought of using comments, but it's not trivial to use formulas inside comments!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `k` constant is a number and not just some value you want to displayed along side whatever is in the cell in a given column, you could make the value of the cell dependent on an unrelated cell in the workbook.

Pretend your data is in `A3:Z800`. Now use cell `A1` as the toggle for whether your `A3:A800` data shows values with or without the constant. Now each cell would take the formula `=<cell value> * if($a$1="ON", <k value for column>, 1)`

You could go further and store the  on another tab and just reference them in the formula above. Say your values were stored in Sheet2 `A3:Z800`, then `=Sheet2!$A$3 * if($a$1="ON", <k value for column>, 1)`

You could also store the `k` values for each column in Row 2 on Sheet1 (above each column of data in `A3:Z800`). Your formula for each cell would look like: `=Sheet2!$A$3 * if($a$1="ON", index($A$2:$Z$2, 1, column()), 1)`

Comment: I understand completely what you're saying! Thankss so much!